# Tracking request and response from anchor element

Tags: html, http, web, dart, angular-dart

I am developing a web application using angular dart.

I am having an anchor element which, when clicked, hits an URL and downloads a document.

I have defined my anchor element like this:

```
AnchorElement elemDownloadLink;
```

And for downloading, i do this:

```
elemDownloadLink.click();
```

My problem is I need to know exactly in code when the HTTP response is received and also if the request is successfull.

Is there any event listener to detect the HTTP response status code?

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Its not the right answer but did you try wireshark just to listen whats send or received...?

Comment: @ZF007 I know what is getting downloaded. In code, I need to know if the request  was completed and if it was successful